# antonym of seriously in a sentence

Tags: meaning

> He studies more seriously than her.

If I change this sentence,

**1. He does not study as slightly as her.**

**2. He does not study as lazily as her.**

> Which one is suitable for the antonym of "seriously" in this sentence, *slightly* or *lazily* ?

Comment: Rather just say "He studies *less* seriously than her."

Answer (score 3):

The person is probably studying "casually." If you want to describe why, they might be studying "absent-mindedly" or "carelessly." If you want to give a judgement about their motivation, yes, they might be studying "lazily."

However, you often want to rework the sentence for a negative comparison, using the positive description and reversing the people described.

```
He does not study as carelessly as her. ->
She does not study as seriously as him.
```

"Slightly" is not appropriate -- slight is a small or partial amount, and is the opposite of a large or complete amount, "fully" "completely" "totally" etc.

"Seriously" is high quality, not high amount -- to study seriously is an intense effort. The most common antonym is "casually." You can do any activity (play a sport, talk) seriously or casually.

Saying that the action is done "lazily" makes a statement about the attitude of the person, not just their level of involvement. Usually being lazy is a moral failing, so the observation is a negative judgement.

English used to have a great many words that were the opposite of "seriously" and indicated moral judgement -- fecklessly, lackadaisically, etc. These still exist but many are no longer in common usage. More current examples: "Carelessly" (not caring about the outcome), "absent-mindedly" (not giving much thought to the task at hand), and "off-handedly" (doing an immediate action without a best effort, as attempting it with your less able hand).